# Add external library to vs code c++ linux

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use [libxl](https://www.libxl.com/home.html) in my c++ project on visual studio code. This is my directory map:

```
├── ken.code-workspace
└── src
    ├── include
    │   ├── AutoFilterA.h
    │   ├── AutoFilterW.h
    │   ├── BookA.h
    │   ├── BookW.h
    │   ├── enum.h
    │   ├── FilterColumnA.h
    │   ├── FilterColumnW.h
    │   ├── FontA.h
    │   ├── FontW.h
    │   ├── FormatA.h
    │   ├── FormatW.h
    │   ├── FormControlA.h
    │   ├── FormControlW.h
    │   ├── handle.h
    │   ├── libxl.h
    │   ├── RichStringA.h
    │   ├── RichStringW.h
    │   ├── setup.h
    │   ├── SheetA.h
    │   └── SheetW.h
    ├── ken.cpp
    └── lib
        └── libxl.so
```

And this is my ken.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "include/libxl.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace libxl;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello babe :)" << endl;
    Book* book = xlCreateBook();
}
```

But I get these errors while trying to compile:

```
/run/media/mahdi/Mahdi/Projects/ken/src/ken.cpp:7:17: error: ‘libxl’ is not a namespace-name
    7 | using namespace libxl;
      |                 ^~~~~
/run/media/mahdi/Mahdi/Projects/ken/src/ken.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/run/media/mahdi/Mahdi/Projects/ken/src/ken.cpp:12:5: error: ‘Book’ was not declared in this scope
   12 |     Book* book = xlCreateBook();
      |     ^~~~
/run/media/mahdi/Mahdi/Projects/ken/src/ken.cpp:12:11: error: ‘book’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘bool’?
   12 |     Book* book = xlCreateBook();
      |           ^~~~
      |           bool
```

I've never added an external library to visual studio code project before. Can I know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are these _all_ the messages produced by the compiler? Doesn't it also complain about missing `libxl.h` or something? Would you mind checking that the `include/libxl.h` file actually contains `namespace libxl`?

Comment: How do you compile or run the Code?

Comment: setup your compile to use `#include "libxl.h"` and not `#include "include/libxl.h"`, there are hundreds of questions on SO on how to use libs and multiple cpp files, many of them have the right answer

Comment: Looks like you're putting the library header directly in your project. The usual suggestion is to install the library and then point the build tool at the library. Error messages look like gcc, so on the command line that's the `-I` and -L` options. I don't use VS Code, so I can't tell you if you set the paths in a configuration dialogue or in a  JSON file.

Comment: On linux you probably should install a distro package instead of copying the headers and binaries to your folder.

Comment: The problem was the way I compiled it, adding these options to command fixed the problem. `-I /run/media/mahdi/Mahdi/Projects/ken/src/include -L /run/media/mahdi/Mahdi/Projects/ken/src/lib -lxl -Wl,-rpath,/run/media/mahdi/Mahdi/Projects/ken/src/lib`.

Thanks for your helps everyone.